# thread still running when another fragment its called

Tags: android, android-fragments, onpause

Hi i have a thread running on a fragment A, and when i called a second fragment, supposedly the fragment A had to called method onPause(), where i stop the thread, but the thread its still running because i have a toast on the first fragment showing a message if the list i have on the fragment A its empty, and it shoy on fragment B, let me paste you the code:

Fragment A:

```
   public class FragmentoPrincipalChofer extends ListFragment {
        private List<ParseObject> mPedido;
        private List<ParseObject> mViaje;
        private List<ParseUser> mUrlUsuario;
        private ListView mLista;
        private Runnable r;
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        private String  mChoferActual;
        private String mPassChofer;
        private   AdaptadorDatosListviewChofer adaptador;





        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {


            View x = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmento_principal_chofer, container, false);
            mLista = (ListView)x.findViewById(android.R.id.list);




            SharedPreferences pref = getContext().getSharedPreferences("login", 0);
            mChoferActual= pref.getString("usuario","");
            mPassChofer= pref.getString("pass","");

            ParseUser.logInInBackground(mChoferActual, mPassChofer, new LogInCallback() {
                public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                    if (user != null) {
                        // Hooray! The user is logged in.
                    } else {
                        // Signup failed. Look at the ParseException to see what happened.
                    }
                }
            });




            return x;

        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();

            // logica de recibir pedidos

            final ProgressDialog dialogoProgreso = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
            dialogoProgreso.setTitle("Cargando");
            dialogoProgreso.setMessage("Buscando Pedidos");
            dialogoProgreso.setCancelable(false);
            dialogoProgreso.show();

                r = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        handler.postDelayed(r, 10000);









                        //obtener pedido de taxi


                        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Pedido");
                        query.whereEqualTo("chofer", mChoferActual);
                        query.addDescendingOrder("createdAt");
                        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                            public void done(List<ParseObject> pedido, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                                if (e == null) {

                                    if(pedido.size()==0){
                                        dialogoProgreso.cancel();


  Toast.makeText(getContext(), "prueba", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                                    }else{

                                        dialogoProgreso.cancel();
                                        mPedido = pedido;
                                        String[] nombreUsuarios = new String[mPedido.size()];
                                        int i = 0;
                                        for (ParseObject pedidos : mPedido) {

                                            nombreUsuarios[i] = pedidos.getString("cliente");
                                            i++;

                                        }



                                        adaptador = new AdaptadorDatosListviewChofer(getListView().getContext(), mPedido);
                                        setListAdapter(adaptador);


                                    }


                                } else {

                                }
                            }
                        });

                    }
                };
                r.run();


            ClickPedido();


        }


        // manejo de click sobre el pedido de taxi
        public void ClickPedido() {

            mLista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                              @Override
                                              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
                                                  final String clienteSeleccionado = mPedido.get(position).get("cliente").toString();
                                                  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());

                                                  builder.setTitle("Confirmacion de pedido")
                                                          .setMessage("Esta seguro que desea tomar el pedido de " + clienteSeleccionado)
                                                          .setPositiveButton("OK",
                                                                  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                                      @Override
                                                                      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                                                          adaptador.remove(mPedido.get(position));
                                                                          adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();


                                                                          ParseQuery<ParseObject> query2 = ParseQuery.getQuery("Pedido");
                                                                          query2.whereEqualTo("cliente", clienteSeleccionado);
                                                                          query2.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                                                                              public void done(ParseObject chofer, ParseException e) {
                                                                                  if (chofer == null) {
                                                                                      Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                                                  } else {

                                                                                      try {

                                                                                          ParseObject viaje = new ParseObject("Viaje");
                                                                                          viaje.put("chofer", mChoferActual);
                                                                                          viaje.put("cliente", chofer.get("cliente").toString());
                                                                                          viaje.saveInBackground();


                                                                                          chofer.delete();
                                                                                          chofer.saveInBackground();


                                                                                          Fragment fragment2 = new MapaChofer();
                                                                                          FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                                                                          transaction.replace(R.id.prueba2, fragment2).addToBackStack(null);
                                                                                          transaction.commit();

                                                                                      } catch (ParseException e1) {
                                                                                          e1.printStackTrace();
                                                                                      }


                                                                                  }
                                                                              }
                                                                          });


                                                                      }

                                                                  }

                                                          )
                                                          .setNegativeButton("CANCELAR",
                                                                  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                                      @Override
                                                                      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                                                          int which) {

                                                                      }
                                                                  }

                                                          );
                                                  builder.show();


                                              }
                                          }

            );


                                    }



        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            handler.removeCallbacks(r);
                    }

       }
```

Main drawer wich manage the fragments:

```
public class DrawerPrincipal extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,FragmentoPrincipalUsuario.OnFragmentInteractionListener {


    private ParseFile mPrueba;
    private Uri url;
    private ImageView imagen;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private String mUsuarioActual;
    public static final int CHOOSE_PIC_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private Uri mMediaUri;
    private ImageView mImagenPrevia;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer_principal);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("login", 0);
        mUsuarioActual= pref.getString("usuario","");









        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        View hView =  navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_drawer_principal);
        final ImageView imgvw = (ImageView)hView.findViewById(R.id.imagenPerfil);
        final TextView tv = (TextView)hView.findViewById(R.id.nombreUsuarioV);
        //Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(url.toString()).into(imgvw);
        tv.setText("new text");

        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query3 = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query3.whereEqualTo("username",mUsuarioActual);
        query3.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            public void done(List<ParseUser> usuario, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {

                    mPrueba = usuario.get(0).getParseFile("foto");
                    tv.setText(usuario.get(0).getUsername().toString());
                    url = Uri.parse(mPrueba.getUrl());
                    Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(url.toString()).transform(new RoundedTransformation(300, 4)).into(imgvw);

                    if (usuario.get(0).get("tipoUsuario").toString().equals("pasajero")) {
                        Fragment fragmento;
                        fragmento = new FragmentoPrincipalUsuario();
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                .replace(R.id.content_main, fragmento)
                                .commit();


                    }else {

                        Fragment fragmento;
                        fragmento = new FragmentoPrincipalChofer();
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                .replace(R.id.content_main, fragmento)
                                .commit();

                    }


                } else {
                    // Something went wrong.
                }
            }
        });




    }



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        DrawerLayout layout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (layout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
        /*
        if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()!=0) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }else{

            super.onBackPressed();
        }*/
    }









    /*
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.pantalla_principal_usuario, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    */
    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.cuenta) {

            Fragment fragmento;
            fragmento = new OpcionDrawerUsuario();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_main, fragmento)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.historial_viajes) {
            Fragment fragmento;
            fragmento = new FragmentoViajesAcumulados();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_main, fragmento)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();


        } else if (id == R.id.contacto) {
            String emailAdress[] = {"gastondelacruz@gmail.com"};
            Intent email= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,emailAdress);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Pon aqui el motivo de tu mail");
            email.setType("text/plain");
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Su mensaje");
            startActivity(email);


        } else if (id == R.id.compartir) {
            String texto="https://www.google.com.ar/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=9JuBVvmcGanX8gejsK_4CA&gws_rd=ssl";
            Intent intento= new Intent();
            intento.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intento.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, texto);
            intento.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(intento);

        } else if (id == R.id.version) {
            String prueba="aceptar";
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("prueba") //
                    .setMessage("Esta es una prueba todavia no poseo el numero de version del producto") //
                    .setPositiveButton(prueba, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // TODO
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }); //

            builder.show();

        } else if (id == R.id.salir) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(DrawerPrincipal.this);
            builder.setTitle("Cerrar Sesion")
                    .setMessage("Esta seguro que desea cerrar sesion actual?")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    ParseUser.logOut();
                                    Intent intento = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActividadLogin.class);
                                    intento.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                    intento.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                    startActivity(intento);
                                    finish();


                                }

                            }

                    )
                    .setNegativeButton("CANCELAR",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                    int which) {

                                }
                            }

                    );
            builder.show();



        }

       DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }







}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually have a thread running in fragment A.  You created a Runnable and called its run method, which causes it to execute immediately in the current thread.  Then it uses a Handler to schedule itself again.  Your Handler is also scheduling work against the main thread, which is the default in this case.

It's really hard to tell what you're trying to do here and the code is not well formatted, but I'm pretty sure you don't want to call r.run() to invoke the Runnable immediately.